# Can we write to file from React?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Currently I'm developing a React web application that needs to store some data from user in the client side and also this data are **Important and should not swap suddenly** so we can't use Indexed DB.

I just thought about using a file to store data as JSON but in a file that can be stored in user computer and also access to read and write it from React.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Persist variables between page loads](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29986657/persist-variables-between-page-loads)

Comment: What do you mean by "*should not swap suddenly*"? Do you want the user be responsible for downloading, storing, and uploading that json file?

Comment: @HereticMonkey No, I don't think so

Comment: @Bergi Yes but not like that, I mean that user may accidentally remove chrome and browser cookies and indexDB and so the data that is important will be removes

Comment: @Sina You can't really guard against that. Either you store the data in localStorage/indexedDB, or you store it for the user on your servers, or you let the user store it themselves as a backup file (that they might still lose).

Comment: And yet, the answers to that question tell you exactly how to save data, client-side, with the ability to read and write from React. As @Bergi says, there is no way of storing user data in a place where a user can't destroy it. If nothing else, they could simply turn off their computer before your program has the chance to save the data.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The best way to work with that is using localStorage.
Cookies are mainly for reading server-side, and local storage can only be read by the client-side.  Other point is saving data, a big technical difference is the size of data you can store, localStorage give you more space.
Check it out https://medium.com/@siobhanpmahoney/local-storage-in-a-react-single-page-application-34ba30fc977d

Comment: I'm looking for a way storing a data that will not removes when user clears the browser cache or cookies

Comment: @Sina LocalStorage is (unlike SessionStorage) not a *cache* that's cleared. It's application data.

Answer (score 2):

What you're looking for is the in-browser [sessionStorage](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/sessionStorage) or [localStorage](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/localStorage). Having the ability a JSON file to a user's computer would be a major vulnerability and is not possible from a browser/client. I suppose you could create one and trigger a download for them to accept–and then have them subsequently re-upload it when you need the data again. But, I'd argue that session/localStorage is more what you're looking for.

Comment: Thanks, I'm agree with you but could you look at draw.io website way that stores the data?

Comment: @Sina You can look at the draw.io site too. Their site is on GitHub: https://github.com/jgraph/drawio